# What does deb-src mean in the sources.list?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, package-management, apt

I know I can download binary packages from repositories beginning with "`deb`", but what does `deb-src` do?

E.g.:

```
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty universe
```

in /etc/apt/sources.list in Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are repositories for source packages. See the `sources.list` man page.

Comment: For the `apt-get source [package-name]` to work, a `deb-src` entry is needed.